# insert data from one table to another in sql server2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

Using the following table

`table1(id,questionid,response,points)`

values

```
1,1,'yes',4

2,1,'no',4

3,1,'copper',2

4,2,'yes',1

5,2,'yes',2
```

want to insert data from  `table1` into `table2(id,ques1,point1,ques2,point2,ques3,point3,ques4,point4,ques5,point5)`

insert response ,points values  into coresponding question1d's

if questionid=1

```
insert into table2 values ques1='yes' and points=4
```

table2 output

```
id,ques1,point1,ques2,point2,ques3,point3,ques4,point4,ques5,point5

1  'yes'  4      'yes'  2      'no'  2    ..........
```

Answer (score 0):

You sample seems to have a mistake or two, but I think you want something similar to this:

```
SELECT id,
    q1.response, q1.points,
    q2.response, q2.points,
    q3.response, q3.points,
    q4.response, q4.points
    q5.response, q5.points
INTO table2
FROM table1 q1
    JOIN table1 q2 ON q1.questionid = q2.questionid
    JOIN table1 q3 ON q2.questionid = q3.questionid
    JOIN table1 q4 ON q3.questionid = q4.questionid
    JOIN table1 q5 ON q4.questionid = q5.questionid
WHERE q1.id = 1 AND q2.id = 2 AND q3.id = 3 AND q4.id = 4 AND q5.id = 5
```

Comment: is there anyway to go with stored procedures?